# Разница между компиляторами c++1y и gnu c++ 11 4.9

Tags: c++, компиляция

У меня запускается код с компилятором gnu++1y, но при использовании gnu c++ 11 4.9 выдает ошибку

```
warning: use of ‘auto’ in lambda parameter declaration only available with -std=c++1y or -std=gnu++1y
     int unique = std::count_if(Mass.cbegin(), Mass.cend(), [](auto pair) { return pair.second == 1; });
```

Как ее исправить? 
Код:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

int main()
{
    std::map<std::size_t, uint> Mass;
    std::string slovo;
    std::hash<std::string> hash_fn;

    int n;
    std::cin >> n; 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        std::cin >> slovo; 
        Mass[hash_fn(slovo)] += 1;
    }


    int unique = std::count_if(Mass.cbegin(), Mass.cend(), [](auto pair) { return pair.second == 1; });
    std::cout << unique << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Переключиться на C++14 или указать в качестве параметра надлежащий тип.

Comment: Можно пример подходящего типа параметра?

Comment: @TimurShleminov Зависит от того, что такое `Mass`.

Comment: `decltype(Mass)::const_reference`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat int n;
    std::cin >> n; //количество запросов
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        std::cin >> slovo; //сам запрос
        Mass[hash_fn(slovo)] += 1;
    }

Comment: @HolyBlackCat привел весь код в исходном посте

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gnu++1y` и `gnu c++ 11 4.9` - не компиляторы. Это режимы компиляции.

`gnu c++ 11 4.9` - стандарт C++11, с расширениями GNU, на компиляторе GCC 4.9.

`gnu++1y` - стандарт C++1y (недоделанный C++14), с расширениями GNU, скорее всего тоже на GCC.

> `use of ‘auto’ in lambda parameter declaration  only available with -std=c++1y or -std=gnu++1y`

Написано, что писать `auto` в параметрах лямбд можно только начиная с C++1y/C++14. Нужно заменить его на обычный тип.

Comment: можно написать как будет выглядеть код с обычным параметром?

Comment: @TimurShleminov Замените `auto` либо на `decltype(Mass)::value_type`, либо `std::pair<std::size_t, uint>`.

Comment: @GolyBlackCat не могли бы написать как полностью будет выглядеть замененная строка с параметром auto?

Comment: @TimurShleminov Нужно просто заменить слово `auto` на один из двух вариантов, больше ничего менять не нужно.